# IF AND OR statement not computing correctly

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having some trouble with my `if` statement, join with `and` and `or`. Could someone tell me why the selected cell is not returning the value of 2? It returns "" even though it is between 6.5 and 6.0. The other problem I am running into is when I format column R to have one decimal place, the selected cell should result in 1.

Column S equation: `=IF(AND(R2<=H2+0.5,R2>=H2-0.5),1,"")`

Column T equation: `=IF(AND(OR(AND(R3<=H3+1,R3>H3+0.5),R3>=H3-1),R3<H3-0.5),2,"")`

Column U equation: `=IF(OR(S2=1,T2=2),"",3)`

The goal of this is to determine how far R3 falls from H3 based on set thresholds. The thresholds are +-0.5, +-1, and outside +-1. For example R3 is larger than H3 + 0.5 and less than or equal to H3 + 1. So T3 should result with a 2.

[image]

Comment: The logic is correct. If (AND(OR(AND(false,true),true),false),2,""). The inner AND is false, the OR is true and the outer AND is hence false.

Comment: It could be helpful to know what your intentions were. Since there are many variable involved and the formula works, we can't say what result is unexpected. Anyway you may try to evaluate the formula step by step and check where it goes wrong: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Comment: @SJR Why is the inner AND false? R3 (6.009) is between 6.0 (H3 + 0.5) and 6.5 (H3 + 1)

Comment: Sorry, you're right but it doesn't make any difference because R3<H3-0.5 is false.

Comment: Which formula? All three formulas are posted.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey see edits, does that help?

Comment: @SJR like that? Also I do see that R3<H3-0.5. I want it to read like in my example. Perhaps switching the first AND and OR?

Comment: Do you need the result in 3 columns because I think you could do this in one - ie. return a different number depending on how far away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My formula for T3:

```
=IF(ABS(H3-R3)>1,"difference > 1",IF(ABS(H3-R3)>=0.5,"difference between 1 and 0.5","difference < 0.5"))
```

This VBA code will write you the formula on a selected cell in the T column:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ABS(RC[-1]-RC[-11])>1,""difference > 1"",IF(ABS(RC[-1]-RC[-11])>=0.5,""difference between 1 and 0.5"",""difference < 0.5""))"
```

You can change the text with numbers as pleased. Does this satisfy you?

Comment: Ah ye, sorry. My default language is not english, so i've copied it from VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it worked for me:

`=IF(AND(R3<=H3+1,R3>H3+0.5),2,IF(AND(R3>=H3-1,R3<H3-0.5),2,""))`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this works for you in a single formula.

Formula in C1 and down is

```
=LOOKUP(ABS(B1-A1),{0,0.5,1},{1,2,3})
```

Comment: This works for the most part, however I do have a value in A that is 6.2 and a value in B that is 4.6 with a result of 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Adjusted above.

Comment: Sorry, but now the problem is if A and B are the same I get a result of 0 when it should be 1.

Comment: Final attempt and then I'll give up.

Comment: Super close again, however when B1 and A1 have an exact 0.5 difference, they should fall into the 1 category, so you could just change is to 0, 0.5000000001,1?? Thank you for the effort!!